# c++ wofstream issue in unicode program

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, unicode, wofstream

Using unicode compile in vs2008
How do you output many language characters to a file in C++ with wofstream?

I can do it in C code no problem e.g.

```
 FILE *out;
 if( (out  = _wfopen( L"test.txt", L"wb" )) != NULL )
 {
     fwprintf(out,L"test\r\n");
     fwprintf(out,L"наказание\r\n");
     fwprintf(out,L"ウェブ全体から検索\r\n");
 }
```

when I open the file it's all correct, but with below C++ program all I get is the first line and I have tried locale::global(locale("")); with same result.

```
 wofstream MyOutputStream(L"test.txt"); 
 if(!MyOutputStream)
 {
    AfxMessageBox(L"Error opening file");
    return;
 }

    MyOutputStream << L"test\r\n";
    MyOutputStream << L"наказание\r\n";
    MyOutputStream << L"ウェブ全体から検索\r\n";

    MyOutputStream.close();
```

and I have tried inserting this with same result:-

```
  std::locale mylocale(""); 
  MyOutputStream.imbue(mylocale);
```

Comment: How do you tell result is wrong. Try open the text file with Notepad and tell notepad to open it as Unicode

Comment: Maybe it's a flushing problem? Try calling MyOutputStream.flush() or adding std::endl somewhere

Comment: I have noticed that the file output is ansi not like with the C code.

Comment: i'm using a hex editor to look at the file afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

worked it out... here it is:-

```
    wofstream MyOutputStream(L"c:\\test2.txt", ios_base::binary);

    wchar_t buffer1[128];  
    MyOutputStream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer1, 128); 
    MyOutputStream.put(0xFEFF);
    MyOutputStream << L"test\r\n";
    MyOutputStream << L"наказание\r\n";
    MyOutputStream << L"ウェブ全体から検索\r\n";
```

Comment: You should not need to supply your own buffer. But outputting a `0xFEFF` character (Unicode codepoint `U+FEFF WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE`) outputs a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the front of the file to help text editors know the file is Unicode encoded.  You could also use `MyOutputStream << L"\xFEFF";` for that instead of `MyOutputStream.put(0xFEFF)`.

Comment: well one would have thought so, but I found trying that I get the no output issue.

Comment: So I took out just the: MyOutputStream.put(0xFEFF);     and it still works/opens correctly in notepad, notepad++.
but without the buffer it doesn't write anything out.
I did notice by opening the C program output txt file that the FEFF wasn't in the file at all.

Comment: the final code that works is:-

  wofstream MyOutputStream(L"c:\\test2.txt", ios_base::binary); 
  if(!MyOutputStream)
  {
  AfxMessageBox(L"Error opening file");
  return;
 }
  wchar_t buffer1[128];  
  MyOutputStream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer1, 128); 

  MyOutputStream << L"test\r\n";
  MyOutputStream << L"наказание\r\n";
  MyOutputStream << L"ウェブ全体から検索\r\n";

                MyOutputStream.close();

Answer (score 0):

the final code that works is:-

```
  wofstream MyOutputStream(L"c:\\test2.txt", ios_base::binary); 
  if(!MyOutputStream)
  {
    AfxMessageBox(L"Error opening file");
    return;
  }
    wchar_t buffer1[128];  
    MyOutputStream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer1, 128); 

    MyOutputStream << L"test\r\n";
    MyOutputStream << L"наказание\r\n";
    MyOutputStream << L"ウェブ全体から検索\r\n";

    MyOutputStream.close();
```

Comment: note: wifstream is the same, have to use the buffer and use ios_base::binary