std::wofstream will stop writting on non ascii
I am trying to write extended character to a file.
My approach was to use an std::wofstream, but the following code will write "foo" and stop there (it does not write the 小, nor the bar).
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
   {
      std::wofstream StreamFileWrite(L"C:\\out.txt");
      if (StreamFileWrite.is_open())
      {
         wchar_t f = 0x0066;
         StreamFileWrite << f;
         StreamFileWrite << L"oo";

         wchar_t c = 0x5C0F; //random unicode symbol
         StreamFileWrite << c;

         StreamFileWrite << L"bar";
      }
      StreamFileWrite.close();
   }
}


What should the be the correct approach for out.txt to contain "foo小bar"?

what do you actually mean when you say "random" ? WHen I tried that unicode on the page you linked it shows no result

Try add: StreamFileWrite.imbue(std::locale{"en_US.UTF-8"}); and std::locale.global(std::locale{"en_US.UTF-8"}); in beginning of main. Note locale names ar not very consistent across platforms (provided version should work everywhere), please specify platform and compiler. What is your current locale set in your system?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+5C0F

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900775

@MarekR Either solution do work perfectly, thank you! (using windows, msvc 2019)

@user7860670 thanks for the link. But the two proposed answer suggest writing as binary... Isn't the locale solutionbetter ?

@sayanel I'm confused. Either is used in negatives and you wrote do work. Also I've provided single solution, AFAIK both lines are required.

(sorry not a native speaker) I meant that StreamFileWrite.imbue(std::locale{"en_US.UTF-8"}); alone is enough. std::locale.global(std::locale{"en_US.UTF-8"}); at the start of the file alone is also enough. According to my tests, only one is required, not both.

Solution with locale prevents stream from actually writing wide chars to output.

@user7860670 this is just matter of selecting encoding in a locale. StreamFileWrite.imbue(std::locale{"en_US.UTF-16"}); and it will write UTF-16.

@MarekR With en_US.UTF-16 vc++ throws runtime error for invalid locale.

@user7860670 My bad. You are right there is no such locale name.

Ok I see why I was wrong. In doc there is: 1200  utf-16  Unicode UTF-16, little endian byte order (BMP of ISO 10646); available only to managed applications
